# "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Hi I'm working on a project where i'm told to create dist ant target which creates JAR file and jrun target which depends on dist target ant should run dist created jar file. While ant jrun i get the folowing error : `jrun
                      [java]: no main manifest attribute in *\build\jar\navus.jar`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="POS" default="build" basedir=".">

<!-- Project properties-->

<property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib"/>
<property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="main.class" value="ee.ut.math.tvt.navus.Intro"/>

<!-- Different classpaths form compiling and running-->

<path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
</path>

    <path id="run.classpath">
            <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
            <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </path>


<!-- Clean existing build-->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />


</target>



<!-- Builds Java code-->

<target name="build" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <copy file="${src.dir}/log4j.properties" todir="${classes.dir}" overwrite="true" />

    <javac 
        srcdir="${src.dir}" 
        destdir="${classes.dir}">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- Creates jar file-->

<target name="dist" depends="build"> 
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <propertyfile file="version.properties">
        <entry key="build.revision.number" type="int" default="0" operation="+"/>
    </propertyfile>

    <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/jar/navus.jar"
         basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="mainClass" value="${main.class}"/>         
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="${src.dir}"/>

        </jar>
</target> 

<!-- Executes application via class Intro-->


    <target name="run"  depends="build"
    description="runs introUI via Intro" >
      <java classname="${main.class}"

        classpathref="run.classpath"
        fork="yes">

      </java>
    </target>


<!-- Runs application using JAR file-->

<target name="jrun" depends="dist"
    description=" Run JAR file">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/navus.jar" 
    fork="yes"/>

</target>


</project>
```

Comment: The manifest.mf file contains the class with the main method you use to start your application. So this is required in the build file - in maven this is     <properties>
        <start-class>app.Application</start-class>
    </properties>. Ant will have something similar

Comment: i get the idea, but dont know how to implement this in ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at google returns https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html. Maybe try something like this -

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="oata.HelloWorld"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a manifest file (MANIFEST.MF), which goes inside the META-INF folder inside your jar.  It resembles this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: MyApp
Sealed: true
Main-Class: com.mysite.myappname.myMainClass
Codebase: www.mysite.com
```